# How would you describe the distribution of this data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

To start I'll say I am relatively new to data analytics.

How is this data set distributed? I'm debating whether I can use the Mann-Whitney test on it along with gender (M/F).

I've been assuming it's very highly skewed but a couple of things are making me question whether it is considered skewed:

- The means and median are the same value (10)
- 90%+ of the observations are the same value (10), so doesn't it fill the standard deviation expectations.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks,
Manny

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should use a more descriptive title, if possible. You have ordinal data (scores between 1 and 10?), where the data is mostly saturating the scale (getting the top value).

Your data seems skewed, because one tail is longer than the other, but I think that the actual issue with your data is that most of it is saturating the scale. That does seem somewhat suboptimal.

However, I think that you should be able to use the Mann-Whitney test to compare two different distributions of the data. If you see the formulation of the Mann-Whitney test [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test), it says:

1. All the observations from both groups are independent of each other,
2. The responses are at least ordinal (i.e., one can at least say, of any two observations, which is the greater),
3. Under the null hypothesis H0, the distributions of both populations are identical.[3]
4. The alternative hypothesis H1 is that the distributions are not identical.

So, it doesn't say anything about assuming normality, or symmetric (i.e. non-skewed) distributions. Thus, you should be able to use the test, whose advantage is precisely being non-parametric, so that it doesn't require much assumptions about the data distribution.

However, with data that is very accumulated on the top value of the scale, it is likely that you won't be able to see a difference with this test (unless you have a lot of data), because I would suppose most of the data of your two distributions would be tied at 10. Although I could be wrong.

Comment: You must beware somewhat of the statements made on Wikipedia in relation to the sort of material that tends to appear in basic non-mathematical courses on statistics that tend to be taught in a wide variety of disciplines. As a result of such subjects, large numbers of people think they understand what they're talking about when an article relates to a term they've heard of and "help" by editing out correct information and replacing it with decidedly incorrect information that they were taught in their class. In this case, the alternative for the Mann-Whitney isn't correct. . . ctd

Comment: ctd. . .  It has doesn't have power to detect a pure difference in spread, for example and so that should not be included as part of the alternative; if you wanted to test against that omnibus alternative, you would use something like a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov. A suitable alternative for the Mann-Whitney is $P(X>Y) \neq P(X<Y)$. That small issue aside, +1.